# Calculate the difference between two dates in number of days

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

What I am trying to do is that when user clicks on a button, I want to calculate and display the difference between two dates.

```
function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) { // input given as Date objects
    var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;

    if (dDate2 < dDate1) return -1; // error code if dates transposed

    var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
    var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;

    if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend

    iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
    iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

    // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
    iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

    if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
        iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
    } else {
        iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
    }

    iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

    return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
}

$("#datepicker, #datepicker1").change(function() {
    alert("getPricing just got called");
    var d1 = $("#datepicker").val();
    var d2 = $("#datepicker1").val();

    var minutes = 1000*60;
    var hours = minutes*60;
    var day = hours*24;

    var startdate1 = getDateFromFormat(d1, "d-m-y");
    var enddate1 = getDateFromFormat(d2, "d-m-y");

    var newstartdate=new Date();
    newstartdate.setFullYear(startdate1.getYear(),startdate1.getMonth(),startdate1.getDay());

    var newenddate=new Date();
    newenddate.setFullYear(enddate1.getYear(),enddate1.getMonth(),enddate1.getDay());

    var days = calcBusinessDays(newstartdate,newenddate);

    if(days>0) {
        $("#leaves_left").val(days);
    } else {
        $("#leaves_left").val(0);
    }
});

$(function() {
    //alert("getPricing just got called");

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShow: function() {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#end_date').val());
        }
    });

    $("#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShow: function() {
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#datepicker').val());
        }
    });

    $("#button").submit(function(){ 
        alert("getPricing just got called");
        var start   = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
        var end = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
        var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
        alert(days);
    });
});
```

[image: screenshot]

**HTML part**

```
<form action="#" method="post" > 
                <dl>
                <dt><span> Leave Reason:</span>
                  <textarea name="reason" required></textarea>
                </dt>
                <br>
              <dd><span> Start Date:</span>
                </dd><br>
              <dd><input type="submit" value="Request" id="button" name="submit"></dd></dl></form>    <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="25" name ="date1"></dd>
              <br>              <dd><span> Expiry Date:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" id="datepicker1" size="25" name ="date2"><br><br>
```

Comment: here is the image url. as i can not attach image to my question.
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2a7tn4x.jpg

Comment: Hi @AQEEL, welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions and answers use [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) formatting; the syntax to add an image is `![alt text](http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg)`. I've edited your post to include the image.

Comment: Can you provide your html structure? At least the main part with the datepicker placeholders ?

Comment: thank you very much. that is something new i learned beside my question :)

Comment: @Nicolas here is the html part. am not able to write code in comments so i uploaded it as picture
![code image](http://oi60.tinypic.com/8vyghv.jpg)

Comment: Can't you just edit your question? I cannot get your image (access denied from here). Or better, create a fiddle

Comment: @Nicolas i am really sorry that i am not able to ask what i actually want. i am totally new to all of this. in my last comment i mentioned my html part image

Comment: AQEEL: I think I understand what you want, just need to see your html code. And right now, with an image, it is not the right way. There is an "edit" button under your question where you will be able to paste the code.

Comment: @NicolasR i just edited the code. Is this is the only part you want to look at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample you are already calculating the business days between the dates when you change the dates with the datepickers. Here I improved this part, still using the calcBusinessDays method you copied from another stackOverflow question:

```
$("#datepicker, #datepicker1").change(function() {
    //alert("getPricing just got called");
    var d1 = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
    var d2 = $("#datepicker1").datepicker("getDate");

    // Calculate only if both dates are defined
    if(d1 != undefined && d2 != undefined) {
        var days = calcBusinessDays(d1,d2);
        if(days > 0) {
            $("#leaves_left").val(days);
        } else {
            $("#leaves_left").val(0);
        }
    }
});
```

You can externalize a part of this method to use it on button click:

```
var d1 = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
var d2 = $("#datepicker1").datepicker("getDate");

// Calculate only if both dates are defined
if(d1 != undefined && d2 != undefined) {
    var days = calcBusinessDays(d1,d2);
    alert(days);
}
```

By the way you should also not use `dl` `dd` `dt` tags for the kind of things you are trying to implement. I cannot give you a fiddle corresponding to your structure, just a basic sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/6h85yvrg/

Comment: alert is not popped up when the button is clicked.

Comment: As I said I showed you how to calculate. For the button click, you have to change the way you implemented: use `click` on submit button, not `submit`. Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/6h85yvrg/2/

Comment: i have seen the sample and it is working fine. but i see that when both the input fields are not empty and if you click on the button, no alert is shown. Y ?

Comment: On the last version I got alerts in each case: if both input are not empty it alerts the number of days, if at least 1 is missing it alerts also (saying that at least 1 is not defined)